# How can I access into my X-UI database with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xui, v2ray

I have a x-ui Xray graphical management panel, I want to build an app in node.js where I can build my own restful api's. I want to create, edit, get inbounds through http protocol. I need to access into it's database so I can build those apis.

I have tried to web scrape the ui, check request that had been made when adding inbound button was clicked, but none of them worked!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the "Burp Suit" app to check API calls, Whenever you are trying to add inbounds there is a network request for it which you can see through your browser's network tab. I used those network requests and created my app successfully (Rest APIs). I am now able to create, edit, delete, and get traffic programmatically by using those APIs.